# Does AWS Glue Scheme Registry support being used as Flink SQL Catalog?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-flink, aws-glue, flink-sql

Does AWS Schema Registry support being used as an SQL Catalog within Flink SQLK applications?  For instance, the [documentation](https://flink.apache.org/2020/07/23/catalogs.html) shows an example of using a Hive Catalog:

```
CREATE CATALOG hive WITH (
'type'='hive',
'property-version'='1',
'hive-version'='2.3.6',
'hive-conf-dir'='/opt/hive-conf'
);
```

The tables defined within that Catalog can then be used within applications without the need for a `CREATE TABLE` statement, e.g. I can then do this:

```
SELECT * FROM hive.`default`.my_table
```

What I'd like to do is something like:

```
CREATE CATALOG awsglue WITH (
...  some config here
);
```

Is this supported and are there any examples or documentation showing its use?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
CREATE CATALOG some_catalog WITH (
    'type'='iceberg',
    'warehouse'='s3://your_bucket/iceberg-test',
    'catalog-impl'='org.apache.iceberg.aws.glue.GlueCatalog',
    'io-impl'='org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO')
```

Additional details: https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/aws/